# Add multiple IPs for one host into /etc/hosts with puppet

Tags: puppet, ipv6

I manage my hosts with puppet. Hosts run dual stack IPv4 and IPv6. I want to add both addresses to /etc/hosts. When I would add it by hand my /etc/hosts file would look like this:

```
192.0.2.1 hostname.example.com hostname
2001:db8::1 hostname.example.com hostname
```

I try to do this with puppet while still being able to add hosts to /etc/hosts by hand.

My first try was the following manifest:

```
host {
  "hostname.example.com":
    ip         => '192.0.2.1',
    host_alias => ["hostname"],
  ;
  "hostname-v6.example.com":
    ip         => '2001:db8::1',
    host_alias => ["hostname","hostname.example.com"],
  ;
}
```

This will result in the following /etc/hosts file:

```
192.0.2.1 hostname.example.com hostname
2001:db8::1 hostname-v6.example.com hostname.example.com hostname
```

This will work but introduce a unneeded second hostname that some applications (e.g. pythons getfqdn()) will return as default hostname.

When I try to decouple the resource name and the hostname in /etc/hosts like this:

```
host {
  "ip4-host":
     name         => "hostname.example.com",
     ip           => '192.0.2.1',
     host_aliases => ["hostname"],
     alias        => 'ipv4-hostname',
     ;
  "ip6-host":
     name         => "hostname.example.com",
     ip           => '2001:db8::1',
     host_aliases => ["hostname"],
     alias        => 'ipv6-hostname',
     ;
}
```

I will get the following error:

```
Cannot alias Host[ipv6-host] to ["hostname.example.com"] at (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/site/mymodule/manifests/init.pp, line: 23); resource ["Host", "hostname.example.com"] already declared (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/site/mymodule/manifests/init.pp, line: 19) (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/site/mymodule/manifests/init.pp, line: 23, column: 9) on node hostname.example.com
```

where Line 19 ist the first host resource and 23 the second.

Currently I write my /etc/hosts with a template but this way I loose the ability to add entries by hand.

Do you have any other idea?

Comment: It's a bug (or shortsighted-ness) with the `host` resource as it doesn't work with dual-stack. It would likely have been better to use the IP address as the namevar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two address families and two names (hostname and hostname.example.com). If it won't let you name both of the resources the same then use one name for each family and add the other as the alias.

Comment: Sorry that I did not mention that. I tried that too. Then I get an error that an Alias can not be created. I will update the description.

Comment: Then what if you name one resource as "hostname.example.com" with "hostname" as an alias and do the reverse for the other one?

Comment: my edit was incomplete. If Do you mean a metaparameter "alias" or the  class paraemter "host_aliases"?

Comment: The same one you used in your original example where you managed to get both "hostname" and "hostname.example.com" in for both IP addresses, but had an extra "hostname-v6.example.com" in there. Instead of "hostname-v6.example.com" as the resource name, what if you use just "hostname"? Then the resource has a different name than the IPv4 one which is using "hostname.example.com".

Comment: that seems to work. I now do the following:

    host {
      'host-v4':
         name         => $::fqdn,
         ip           => '192.0.2.1',
         host_aliases => [$::hostname],
         ;
      'host-v6':
         name         => $::hostname,
         ip           => '2001:db8::1',
         host_aliases => [$::fqdn],
         ;
    }

that will add two lines with swaped fqdn and hostname. That is not exactly what I wanted but close.

Comment: I will check if that has some side-affects. Would you please be so kind and modify your answer that I can accept it.

Comment: There you are then.